# How to change page in view pager when user change/swipe page?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, fragmentpageradapter

I have taken a view pager in an application. In which there are three pages. On first page there is menu i.e. Fragment. In menu there are six buttons. When user clicks on a menu button it will move view pager to Page 2 and replacing with a fragment according menu button pressed. So there is six different fragments.

[image: View pager with three pages.]

Now I want to add one more condition, if user doesn't press any button from menu and user change page by swipe then it should automatically load a common different fragment i.e. Sevent Fragment in view pager's Page 2.

Is it possible to do in any way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is a method currentItem of the pager, use that to set to it 1, and then on a condition may be load the appropriate fragment or view rather

Comment: I have tried it on onPageSelected. Is it the method? About which you asked.

Comment: `pager.setCurrentItem( num )` this method

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to pass some flag from the activity on button click and based on that you can load fragment in other page. there is no predefined ways in android to achieve this.